# Compose LazyColumn with Paging3 scrolls up when item updated

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose, kotlin-flow, android-paging-3, android-jetpack-compose-lazy-column

I am using `Paging3` with `RemoteMediator` for getting remote data, saving it in `Room` database and showing it in my `Composable` screen. On item click, opens detail screen and can update the data of that item saved in database. Whenever an item it's updated, because the paged data is collected as a `Flow`, it automatically updates de list.

**The problem is that whenever an update is done in the detail view, once I go back, the list scrolls (without seeing the scrolling effect) up till the top of the list, like if the whole list was updated instead of just that item.**

the screen:

```
@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@SuppressLint("UnusedMaterial3ScaffoldPaddingParameter")

@Composable
fun ReposListScreen(navController: NavController,
                    viewModel: RepositoriesViewModel = hiltViewModel()) {

val repos = viewModel.data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()
val snackBarHostState = remember { SnackbarHostState() }
val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

Scaffold(
    topBar = {
        TopAppBar(
            title = { Text(text = stringResource(id = R.string.str_best_rated_repos)) }
        )
    },
    snackbarHost = { SnackbarHost(snackBarHostState) },
    bottomBar = {
        BottomNavigationBarComponent() {
            coroutineScope.launch {
                snackBarHostState.showSnackbar("You pressed $it.")
            }
        }
    }
) {
    LazyColumn(
        modifier = Modifier.padding(paddingValues = it)
    ) {

        when (val appendState = repos.loadState.append) {
            is LoadState.Loading -> {
                item { LoadingNextPageItem(modifier = Modifier.fillMaxWidth()) }
            }

            is LoadState.Error -> {
                item {
                    ErrorMessage(
                        modifier = Modifier
                            .fillMaxWidth(),
                        message = appendState.error.localizedMessage.orEmpty(),
                        onClickRetry = { repos.retry() }
                    )
                }
            }

            else -> {}
        }

        items(count = repos.itemCount, key = repos.itemKey { it.id }) { index ->
            repos[index]?.let { repo ->
                RepoItem(
                    repo,
                    onRepoClicked = {
                        navController.navigate(Routes.RepoDetailScreen.createRoute(repo.id))
                    }
                )
            }
        }

        item { Spacer(modifier = Modifier.padding(4.dp)) }
    }
}
```

}

the viewmodel:

```
@HiltViewModel
class RepositoriesViewModel @Inject constructor(
    private val getPagedBestRatedReposUseCase: GetPagedBestRatedReposUseCase
) : ViewModel() {
private var _state: MutableStateFlow<UiState> = MutableStateFlow(UiState(loading = true))
val state: StateFlow<UiState> = _state.asStateFlow()

private var _data: MutableStateFlow<PagingData<Repository>> =
    MutableStateFlow(PagingData.empty())
val data: StateFlow<PagingData<Repository>> = _data.asStateFlow()

init {
    viewModelScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
        _state.value = UiState(loading = true)
        getPagedBestRatedReposUseCase()
            .cachedIn(viewModelScope)
            .catch {
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(error = true, loading = false)
                }
            }
            .collect { repos ->
                _state.update {
                    it.copy(
                        dataSource = repos,
                        loading = false, error = false
                    )
                }
                _data.update { repos }
            }
    }
}
```

}

**THE ANSWER BELOW**

Okey, I found the answer thanks to @BenjyTec comment, that guided me till this issue: Google Issue

The thing is that val data = viewModel.data.collectAsLazyPagingItems() should be called before the initialization of the NavHost, and I was calling it in a composable screen called inside NavHost.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okey, I found the answer thanks to @BenjyTec comment, that guided me till this issue: [Google Issue](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/177245496)

The thing is that
`val data = viewModel.data.collectAsLazyPagingItems()`
should be called before the initialization of the `NavHost`, and I was calling it in a composable screen called inside NavHost.

Answer (score 1):

You shouldn't collect `Flow<PagingData>` inside of your ViewModel to make `StateFlow` out of it, that's wrong and it's causing your problem. Also, the way you handle loading and error states is wrong - `.catch` will never be called, as paging never throws exceptions but rather handles the errors internally. You should expose the paging flow as you get it from the library:

```kotlin
val data = getPagedBestRatedReposUseCase().cachedIn(viewModelScope)
```

then in your composable, you collect it with `collectAsLazyPagingItems()`. The resulting `LazyPagingItems` instance has the items, but also `loadState` , which you should use instead of your own loading and error implementation.

Comment: need to call it in init{} method because needs viewModelScope to call suspend function. Then, if data is lateinit var, crashes when screen tries to collect it because it is not initialized; if data is nullable, it is not receiving data

Comment: which function is suspend? `getPagedBestRatedReposUseCase()`? It shouldn't be suspend then, why you need it to be suspend?

Comment: or you can do `flowOf(Unit).flatMapLatest { getPagedBestRatedReposUseCase() }.cachedIn(viewModelScope)`

Comment: I just did what you said, removed the suspended and cache it it data val. Not working either, happens the same, scrolls till first element

Answer (score 0):

The `LazyColumn` should store the scroll position by default. There is however an [issue on the Google Issue Tracker](https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/179397301) that describes the same problem.

It might happen in your case that while you navigate to the next screen and then come back, the Composable resubscribes to the Flow, and while that happens, the `Flow` is reset to the initial value for a moment.

In this short moment however, the scroll position of the `LazyColumn` is reset and not restored when the actual `Flow` data comes back in.

As a workaround, you can try to resolve it as follows:

```
if (repos.isNotEmpty()) {
    LazyColumn() {
       // .....
    }
}
```

This might prevent the scroll position to be reset when the list is empty for a moment.

---

Alternatively, you can store and restore the scroll position in your ViewModel. First, add two new properties to your ViewModel:

```
class HomeViewModel () : ViewModel() {

    // store the current scroll states
    var scrollIndex: Int by mutableStateOf(0)
    var scrollOffset: Int by mutableStateOf(0)
}
```

Then you could access these two fields as follows:

```
@Composable
HomeScreen(viewModel: HomeViewModel = viewModel()) {

    val scrollState: LazyListState = rememberLazyListState(
        viewModel.scrollIndex, 
        viewModel.scrollOffset
    )

    // after each scroll, update values in ViewModel
    LaunchedEffect(key1 = scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
        if (!scrollState.isScrollInProgress) {
            viewModel.scrollIndex = scrollState.firstVisibleItemIndex
            viewModel.scrollOffset = scrollState.firstVisibleItemScrollOffset
        }
    }
}
```

And assign the `scrollState` to the `LazyColumn` as follows:

```
LazyColumn(state = scrollState, /** ... **/) {
    //...
}
```